# Not able to connect to mysql Docker when VPN was ON

Tags: mysql, docker, networking, sonicwall

I have mysql Docker installation and i am able to connect successfully without any issues. The actual problems are started when i turn ON the VPN not able to connect it. I am trying to check connectivity with `telnet localhost 3306`
Environment:
Ubuntu
Mysql Docker
Sonicwall NetExtender

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should try to check:

docker inspect container_name | grep IPAddress (Check the IP address and port number)

docker network inspect network_name (Check the Docker network configuration)

Check the VPN configuration, both of client and server side connect correctly to VPN

Check the MySQL user permissions, if you give the permissions to connect from remote hosts

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%'; 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Before VPN : When i  check docker inspect container_name | grep IPAddress  its showing IPAdress as 172.18.0.3 And am able to telnet with localhost and as well ad with 172.18.0.3

After VPN : My Ip was allocated to 192.X..and then i am not able to do telnet with either of above (localhost, 172.18.0.3).